# Intellij IDEA: renaming like in Visual Studio / C#

Tags: visual-studio, ide, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there such a feature in IDEA, that after renaming certain declared variable or field, I can apply to rename all occurrences of it? Like in VS after renaming something, appears some red, small triangle at bottom right of the word, that pushing it, VS updates all occurrences.

Comment: Future?  IntelliJ does that now.  You can rename all occurrences in selected text, a file, or throughout your entire project.  That's been so for years.

Comment: read one more time my question...

Comment: Still don't get it.  Re-write your question.

Comment: In Visual Studio, when you rename some variable NOT IN FIND AND REPLACE, after renaming, appears little, red rectangle at the end of edited word, that pushing it, VS renames all occurrences automatically, without need to enter find and replace.

Comment: No, IntelliJ doesn't do such a thing.  I don't see the usefulness of it.  Why would I rename x to y and then continue to edit x into the code in the future?

Comment: IDE just renames for you all occurrences on the fly when you rename one of them, without doing nothing, isn't it convenient?

Comment: @nik, VS doesn't "rename on the fly without doing nothing", you still have to click/use a shortcut for that red rectangle. If you want to rename and you know that you're renaming, use Idea's `Shift+F6`

Comment: No, once I rename a variable I use the new name from that point on.  Not convenient for me.

Comment: @Vic, Shift + F6 is almost the answer for me, so you can write it like an answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  <kbd>Shift + F6</kbd> for an in-place rename.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Set cursor on your variable and then select in menu Refactor -> Rename...

Idea will automaticly detect if it is needed to rename other occurrences.